how can I overlay a normal map on an object that already has small repeating texture maps
i have a texture image that is quite small so i need to repeat it alot to make it look right on my model, i also have a normal map that is the correct size for the polygon i want to place it on. i would like to place the normal map over the repeating textures so one normal map is the size of 10X10 images of the texture. i basicaly want to know a way i can project the normal map over a section of the object that has nothing to do with the texture node

You just need to use 2 Mapping nodes, plug an Input > Value node into the Scale input of the Mapping node of your image texture and set it to 10:

